# Как скрыть/показать свойство в PropertyGrid при изменении другого свойства?

Tags: c#, winforms

В PropertyGrid есть 3 поля. Первое - текстовое, при заполнении которого должны отображаться 2 других поля, у которых пока стоит [Browsable(false)]. Второе поле - список, третье - текстовое, при выборе значения из списка (кроме стандартное первого), третье поле должно быть не доступно ([ReadOnly(true)]). Может возможно переключение атрибутов во время выполнения программы?

Comment: [PropertyGrid FAQ](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml#EFKAE)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо